# ADT - How do I graphicly edit a scrollview that is bigger than the screen size?

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I am working on an application for android. 
I have a scrollview that needs to hold many many things.
I want to graphicly edit it and add all these things but I can only edit what fits on the screen..

Is there any way to edit it height wise besides selecting 10 inch tablet view?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to try Android Studio. The graphic layout designer view extends to wrap the content of a ScrollView, so you can always see everything in the ScrollView.

Comment: ^ @myanimal Please submit as answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html).

The graphic layout designer view extends to wrap the content of a `ScrollView`, so you can always see everything in the `ScrollView`.